# How can I use Angular data binding to render component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

On my `dashboard.component.html` I have the following code:

`<div [innerHTML]="myComponent"></div>`

Inside of `dashboard.component.ts` I have the following code:

`myComponent = "<app-messages></app-messages>"`

I want it to render the messages component there. But it just appears blank. If I switch the code in the html to simply be `<div><app-messages></app-messages></div>` then it works as expected, but I don't want to directly include it like that.

In case you are curious why I need this, it is because I am including an `ngFor` and only want to render, in order, the components in a certain bucket array within dashboard.component.ts.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot render an Angular component from a string at run-time.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: It would be simpler to use separate component for app-messages. Every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality. (single responsibility principle)

Comment: @ProkhorSednev Agreed, and yes app-messages is indeed a separate component already. The point is that I need to instantiate it from a variable in my dashboard.component.ts and not directly in my dashboard.component.html (the standard way)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is yet to use ngFor here. You can also use dynamic component loading, but this would be overkill in this case.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'items',
    template: `
      <item *ngFor="let i of service.items;" [name]="i"></item>
    `,
})
export class ItemsComponent {
    constructor(public service: ItemsService) { }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'item',
    template: `<div>{{name}}</div>`,
})
export class ItemComponent {
    @Input() name: string;
}
```

Working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-audxwo